# なのもなんだし what is this nuance?

Tags: particle-の, sentence-final-particles

[image]

I'm finding some examples of the use なんだし online but I'm not quite sure how it's being used in this very sentence.

In the right bubble the character wonders if inviting another person to their school club maybe was too sudden.

Then in the left bubble, he contemplates that they are always alone the two of them at club. What I'm struggling is the final meaning of なんだし. My vague understanding seems to be akin to "But it's because just being alone always the two of us is weird".

Comment: What is this from? If published, when?

Comment: So it's kinda like "But being always the two of us is, you know..." ? As for the manga, it's freely published online: https://comic-action.com/episode/14079602755194839222

Comment: @Kawase_K Yes, your translation seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to parse the grammar of the individual parts?

In いつまでも二人きりなの is a nominalized form of the sentence

> いつまでも二人きりだ

Are you able to parse this? "It's always [those] two together".

So, back to the quote, we have

> [noun]もなんだし

This なんだ is なのだ. So we have two embedded nominalizations going on.

> [[いつまでも二人きりなの]もなん]だ

So he's remarking on the fact that he feels it was somewhat sudden he brought a third into the group.

> Was that too sudden?  Afterall, it's usually just the two of us.

Comment: For context the "いつまでも二人きりだ" is about him, he's the one who invited the third person at the club hes' always alone wit  the other person.

Comment: @Kawase_K That helps.